# Aplicación se detiene con Button.setOnClickListener(this); error

Tags: android

Tengo una aplicación, que para iniciar sesión esta conectado a cuentas almacenadas en Firebase, la cosa es que cuando estoy en el login, le doy CLIC en le botón INICIAR SESIÓN sin ingresar datos quiero que me salga en los campos un mensaje de error. Y cuando inicio sesión sin poner ningún dato en los campos, la app se detiene y se cierra. Lo que quiero es que inicie sesión normal cuando se ingresan los datos, y cuando no, que aparezca un mensaje de error en los editText sin que se detenga la app.

Este es el código del LoginActivity.java

```
  public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button buttonSignIn,buttonVentanaRegistrar;
EditText editTextEmail, editTextPass;

public static  String userEmail;

FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    buttonSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonVentanaRegistrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ventana_registrar);
    buttonVentanaRegistrar.setOnClickListener(this);

    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.correo_login);
    editTextPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contraseña_login);


    //CODIGO QUE IMPLEMENTE PARA QUE DE ERROR CUANDO NO SE INGRESA NINGUN DATO
    /*buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(editTextEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                editTextEmail.setError("Ingrese usuario");
                 }
            if(editTextPass.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                editTextPass.setError("Ingrese contraseña");
            }

                if (editTextEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty() && editTextPass.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    editTextEmail.setError("Ingrese usuario");
                    editTextPass.setError("Ingrese contraseña");
                }
                else{

                }
          }
    });*/




    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if(user != null){

           //     startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CatalogoActivity.class));
             //   finish();
            }else{

                //Log.i("SESION","Sesion cerrada");
            }

        }
    };

}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()){
         case R.id.btn_login:
           String email_login = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
            String pass_Login  = editTextPass.getText().toString();
            iniciarSesion(email_login,pass_Login);
              break;


        case R.id.btn_ventana_registrar:
            Intent siguienteVentana = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegistroActivity.class);
            startActivity(siguienteVentana);
            break;
    }


}

private void iniciarSesion(String email,String pass){
    userEmail = email;
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                //mensaje("Inicio de sesion correctamente");
                Intent siguienteVentana = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CatalogoActivity.class);
                startActivity(siguienteVentana);
            }else{
                mensaje(task.getException().getMessage()+"");
            }


          }


    });

}



@Override
protected  void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected  void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(mAuthListener != null){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

}

public void mensaje(String mensaje){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(mensaje)
            .setTitle("Mensaje")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNeutralButton("Aceptar",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}

He logrado agregar el mensaje de error en los editText con el "setError", pero quitando el "buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(this); error", y cuando le doy a INICIAR SESIÓN, no ocurre nada, no inicia sesión y se queda en el login, pero si dejo normal el "buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(this); error" cuando le doy INICIAR SESIÓN sin poner ningún dato, la app se detiene y se cierra.

Comment: que es lo que sale en tu log?

Comment: No me sale ningún error. No uso el emulador del Android Studio, uso el Nox Player

Comment: Comprueba que al elemento que le estás añadiendo el setOnClickListener no sea nulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que tienes comentado está correcto pero ya no deberías de usarlo así, puesto que ya implementaste el `onClickListener` al momento de que colocaste el `this`. Puedes copiar este código:

```
if(editTextEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
   editTextEmail.setError("Ingrese usuario");
} else if(editTextPass.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
   editTextPass.setError("Ingrese contraseña");
} else {
   iniciarSesion(email_login,pass_Login);
}
```

Y meterlo dentro de un método que se llame verificar, con esto comparas el primer campo, después el segundo y si ambos están correctos entonces se llama el método iniciarSesion.

Y en el switch que tienes, en lugar de llamar a iniciarSesion llamas al método de verificar:

```
case R.id.btn_login:
     String email_login = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
     String pass_Login  = editTextPass.getText().toString();
     verificar(email_login,pass_Login);
     break;
```

Si tienes dudas, me avisas con un comentario.